# Crontab not running as expected with PHP curl doing a HTTP Patch

Tags: php, curl, cron

I created a php script that reads a third-party API to produce data.  I want to write this data to a file in my site's www folder and also do an HTTP Patch to update the API for the records I have read.

The problem is that when I run my program using crontab, doing the HTTP patch causes the file to not be written properly.

My crontab job is as follows:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/status/www/active-cron.php
```

My PHP script is similar to this one:

```
<?php
#
#
define("TIME_ZONE", "America/New_York");
define("TICKET_TYPE", 12713);


#
# New, Open, InProcess, Posted
define("STATUS_NEW", 10963);
define("STATUS_OPEN", 10964);
define("WWW_ROOT", __ROOT__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."www".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

$url = "https://api.url.com/web/api/";
$appId = "123";
$data = array();
$file = WWW_ROOT."files/report.json";

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

function add_ticket($ticket){
    $key = $find_key($ticket["ID"], $data, "ID");
    if($key===false)
        $data[] = $ticket;
}
function cpatch($params){
    #
    # Perform HTTP POST
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $params["url"]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization: Bearer '.get_token()));
    if(isset($params["fields"]))
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params["fields"]);
    return $ch;
}
function cpost($params){
    # Perform HTTP POST
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $params["url"]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                         
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization: Bearer '.get_token()));
    if(isset($params["fields"]))
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params["fields"]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    return $ch;
}
function find_key($key, $arr, $col){
    for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
        if(trim($key) == trim($arr[$i][$col]))
            return $i;
    return false;
}
function get_status_tickets($fields){
    $ch = cpost(array("url" => $url.$appId.'/tickets/search', "fields" => $fields));
    #
    # Return array of tickets
    return json_decode(send_request($ch, "get_ticket_list_as_json"), true);
}
function new_tickets(){
    $search_date = new DateTime("NOW",  new DateTimeZone(TIME_ZONE));
    $search_date->sub(new DateInterval("P2M"));
    return get_status_tickets(json_encode(array(
        "TypeIDs" => array(TICKET_TYPE),
        "StatusIDs" => array(STATUS_NEW),
        "CreatedDateFrom" => $search_date->format(DATE_FORMAT)
    )));
}
function parse_ticket($ticket, $get_feed=true){
    #
    # array for output
    $output = array();
    $output["ID"] = intval($ticket["ID"]);
    $output["Title"] = $ticket["Title"];
    #
    # Dates
    $created = new DateTime($ticket["CreatedDate"], TIME_ZONE);
    $output["Created"] = $created->getTimestamp();
    if(!empty($ticket["StartDate"])){
        $sdate = new DateTime($ticket["StartDate"], TIME_ZONE);
        $edate = new DateTime($ticket["EndDate"], TIME_ZONE);

        $output["StartDate"] = $sdate->getTimestamp();
        $output["EndDate"] = $edate->getTimestamp();
    }
    #
    # Attributes. Deal with each case and set a default.
    $output["Feed"] = "";

    #
    # Return output as an array
    return $output;
}
function patch_ticket($id, $params){
    $url = $url.$appId."/tickets/".$id;
    $ch = cpatch(array("url"=>$url, "fields" => $params));
    return send_request($ch);
}
function send_request($ch, $calling_function=""){
    $curl = $ch;
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $ret = $action = "";
    if(intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) < 300){
        return $result;
    }
}
#
# Get some tickets
$tickets = new_tickets();
#
# Update tickets, changing status from New to Posted
$patch = json_encode(array(0 => array("op" => "replace", "path" => '/StatusID', "value" => STATUS_POSTED)));

#
# Get ticket detail from the tickets and add them to the array.
foreach($tickets as $key => $ticket){
    add_ticket($ticket);
}

#
# Save new Tickets and RSS feed
if(count($data) > 0){
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($status->get_data()));
}
foreach($data as $key => $val){
    #
    # Change Status from New to Posted
    $result = patch_ticket($val["ID"], $patch);
}
?>
```

When I run the script via the web browser, the script will take the input $file, add the new records to it, update the records in the application API and write the new plus the old records to the file as a JSON string.

When I let the cron job run the script, it updates the application API that I am calling fine, but takes the new record, adds it to the file at index[0] and deletes the record from the file that was in index[0].  When the cron job runs again and someone has added a new record to the API, the job adds the record at index[0] but deletes what was added in the previous run.

Example:

```
Existing file:
[  
    {  
        "ID":1584856,
        "Title":"Wiki server goin down",
        "Created":1462567488,
        "StartDate":1463630400,
        "EndDate":1463716800,
        "SystemChangedID":50910,
        "SystemChanged":"Wiki Server",
        "IncidentType":"Disruption",
        "Description":"We are getting rid of this monster",
        "Feed":[  

        ]
    },
    {  
        "ID":1584799,
        "Title":"Mailscape Mutilation!!!",
        "Created":1462566562,
        "StartDate":1463630400,
        "EndDate":1463716800,
        "SystemChangedID":50950,
        "SystemChanged":"Mailscape",
        "IncidentType":"Disruption",
        "Description":"Friday night!! Come on down to the arena!!! and witness MAILSCAPE MUTILATION!!!!",
        "Feed":[  

        ]
    }
]

After running with crontab: 
[  
    {  
        "ID":1584905,
        "Title":"Mortimore the terrible",
        "Created":1462568556,
        "StartDate":1463544000,
        "EndDate":1462568583,
        "SystemChangedID":50883,
        "SystemChanged":"ASSETs - Automated Security Self-Evaluation Tools",
        "IncidentType":"Disruption",
        "Description":"eat at joes",
        "Feed":[  

        ]
    },
    {  
        "ID":1584799,
        "Title":"Mailscape Mutilation!!!",
        "Created":1462566562,
        "StartDate":1463630400,
        "EndDate":1463716800,
        "SystemChangedID":50950,
        "SystemChanged":"Mailscape",
        "IncidentType":"Disruption",
        "Description":"Friday night!! Come on down to the arena!!! and witness MAILSCAPE MUTILATION!!!!",
        "Feed":[  

        ]
    }
]
```

What would be causing the unexpected results when doing an HTTP Patch via curl?

Comment: Is it your use of global variables? Global vars are not available to a cron-invoked PHP script, but they are if you run it via curl within the crontab: * * * * * curl http://www.your-domain.com/active-cron.php

Comment: I don't think so.  My job runs without errors from the command line.  And it does do the patch which is at the end of the script after the other part runs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append your data:

`file_put_contents($file, json_encode($status->get_data()), FILE_APPEND);`